# How to extract email:pass using batch or vbs?

Tags: windows, email, batch, vbscript

**I have a text file named `file.txt` which contains,**

```
myname1234@gmail.com:
myname1234@gmail.com:password000
secondmail@hotmail.com:
secondmail@hotmail.com:qwerty123
philip007@ymail.com:
philip007@ymail.com:iloveyou
```

**I am running a vbs program,**

```
Const SCRIPT_NAME = "Extract E-mail Addresses"
Dim objFSO, objFil, arrAdr, varBuf, varInp, varOtp
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFil = objFSO.OpenTextFile("file.txt")
varBuf = objFil.ReadAll
objFil.Close
arrAdr = Split(FindString(varBuf, "\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b"), ",")
Set objFil = objFSO.CreateTextFile("results.txt")
For Each varBuf In arrAdr
    objFil.WriteLine varBuf
Next
objFil.Close
Set objFil = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
MsgBox "Extraction complete.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, SCRIPT_NAME
WScript.Quit

Function FindString(strText, strFind)
    Dim objRegEx, colMatches, objMatch
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBscript.RegExp")
    With objRegEx
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = strFind
        Set colMatches = .Execute(strText)
    End With
    For Each objMatch In colMatches
        FindString = FindString & objMatch.Value & ","
    Next
    If Len(FindString) > 0 Then
        FindString = Left(FindString, Len(FindString) - 1)
    End If
    Set objRegEx = Nothing
    Set colMatches = Nothing
    Set objMatch = Nothing
End Function
```

**Expected output,**

```
myname1234@gmail.com:password000
secondmail@hotmail.com:qwerty123
philip007@ymail.com:iloveyou
```

**But, Actual result,**

```
myname1234@gmail.com
myname1234@gmail.com
secondmail@hotmail.com
secondmail@hotmail.com
philip007@ymail.com
philip007@ymail.com
```

**My need :** I like to filter only email:password from the `file.txt` text file. But, using above vbs i can only able to filter email address. Please fix my code to get my expected output. Thanks a lot in advance.

**Note :** The email and password may vary with different text files. Also am noob to vbs. Being frank i got the above code from Quora. Kindly help me. Even same solution using batch program is also fine for me. Waiting for valuble solutions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vbs
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set File = FSO.OpenTextFile("file.txt")
Buffer = Split(File.ReadAll, vbNewLine)
File.Close
Set File = FSO.CreateTextFile("output.txt")
For Each Line In Buffer
    If Trim(Split(Line & ":", ":")(1)) <> "" Then
        File.WriteLine Line
    End If
Next
File.Close
```

Comment: This works, Give Expected output. But, Gives this error - https://i.postimg.cc/dQpwG5d7/Capture.png

Comment: @Philip It is because the input file format does not match the one shown. Code updated.

Comment: Perfect now without error. :) Thanks a lot bro. U made my work easier.